# Django Rest Framework: URL endpoint to add 'Favorite/Like/Rate' functionality when using Viewsets?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created a "Recipe" viewset and I would like the functionality of people to be able to favorite different recipes.

My Viewset is very simple and it looks something like this:

```
class RecipeViewset(ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.filter(enabled=True)
    serializer_class = RoutineSerializer
```

My urls.py is using a SimpleRouter (Right now I dont have any url patterns so im leaving it empty:

```
urlpatterns = []
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('recipes', views.RecipeViewset, basename='recipes')
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

This creates 2 endpoints for the list and detail:

```
www.example.com/recipes
www.example.com/recipes/1
```

I have several options in mind of how the endpoint to favorite the recipe could look like:

```
www.example.com/recipes/1/favorite
www.example.com/recipes/favorite/1
www.example.com/favorite/recipes/1
www.example.com/recipes-favorite/1
```

Which would be the best approach and does Django provide an easy way to achieve this?

Could Viewset @action decorator be used for this?

PS: The user will send the Auth Token in the headers so it's not required to be sent in the URL.

Comment: How are you setting your endpoint paths? Can you show us your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a question that will most likely be answered with opinions rather than facts, since API design is very subjective to the contract between development and consumers.

Here are some links for API sub resource design tips: [[1]](https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/api-design/REST-API-Design-Best-Practices-for-Sub-and-Nested-Resources/) [[2]](https://www.kennethlange.com/7-tips-for-designing-a-better-rest-api/).

However to make use of nested resources in DRF I think that you should use [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers), since they provide a similar interface to what you've already have.

For that I think it would be easier to make this endpoint `www.example.com/recipes/1/favorite`, since it already has examples on the documentation and seem to work just fine.